# How can I return a field value from a child in a custom object in a relationship using SOQL?

Tags: soql, rest-api

I run into an error when I try to execute the following **SOQL** query (I need it to return results from Salesforce via the REST API):

```
SELECT Id, Name, Principle_Sales_Rep__c, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Sales_Rep__r) FROM Account
```

However when I replace the custom object with an sObject such as Contact the query runs without issues.

```
SELECT Id, Name, Principle_Sales_Rep__c, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account
```

I would like to know if this is a limitation of SOQL (although I haven't come across this in my researching). (I have checked my syntax and it appears to be correct and the custom objects DO exist etc.etc.

Comment: Do you have the error message text that is given to you when you try to execute the first query? (I presume it's something about an invalid relationship)

Comment: Yes, here it is: "INVALID_TYPE: 
Principle_Sales_Rep__c, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Sales_Rep__r) FROM Account
                                              ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:64
Didn't understand relationship 'Sales_Rep__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."

Comment: Its likely that Sales_Rep__r is not the relationship name, which is what you provide here not the object name. Review the Account lookup field on your sales rep object and make a note of the 'Child Relationship Name', then add __r on the end of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The child relationship is usually named in plural form, i.e. `Contact` is the name of the object and `Contacts` is the name of the child relationship under the `Account` object. Hence you can query using the child relationship name in your nested query using `Contacts`.

You'll need to determine the name of the child relationship between these two objects. Following the typical pattern when relationships are configured between objects, I would guess that it will look like this where the name of the child object is `Sales_Rep__c`, it will probably have a configured relationship name of `Sales_Reps__r`:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Principle_Sales_Rep__c, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Sales_Reps__r) FROM Account
```

You can find the child relationship name through the Salesforce UI if you look at the definition of the `Sales_Rep__c` object and view the details of the relationship to the `Account` object. It is listed in the **Lookup Options** section of the detail page.

It can also be found in Eclipse & force.com IDE using the schema explorer (at the bottom of the project structure) and expanding the `Account` object in the list and then expanding **Child Relationships** and expand the relationship with the `Sales_Rep__c` object. The relationship name will be listed there.

Comment: OK, thanks for that, so if I have an sObject (Account) which has a lookup relationship to a custom object (Sales_Rep__c) and this lookup child relationship, i.e., a rep can have many Accounts, name is "Accounts" and I want to return the Name__c field in the Sales_Rep__c along with the Name field from the Account, I thought that I would have to have the following syntax: SELECT Name, (SELECT Name__c FROM Accounts__r) from Account.

Comment: The name of the relationship is defined on the lookup field. It'll be up to you to determine the name that is configured in the org. If indeed the name of the relationship defined on the lookup field is Accounts and you are looking for a list of Sales Reps and then under each one having a list of their Accounts the query will probably look similar to this: `SELECT Id, Name, (Id, Name FROM Accounts__r) FROM Sales_Rep__c`

Comment: Yes that's it, working fine now (you had left out the inner 'SELECT' but once that was back in the query worked) , thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. If this answer was useful, it would be great if you could accept it.

Comment: ...and my apologies, done that now.